# How to change search model for using one field

Tags: search, crud, yii2

I have CRUD generated bu Gii. By default, the search in app use one field for each table column. How should i change my search model, for make search in all columns via alone field?

That's my model:

```
class UserSearch extends User
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['username', 'auth_key', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = User::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'auth_key', $this->auth_key])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'password_hash', $this->password_hash])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'password_reset_token', $this->password_reset_token])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
 public function search($params)
    {
        ..............................
        if($this->keyword) {
            if(preg_match("/[A-Za-z]+/", $this->keyword) == true) {
                $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'LOWER(CONCAT(name, age, WHATEVERFIELDS)), ', strtolower($this->keyword)]);
            } else {
                $query->andFilterWhere(['id' => $this->keyword]);
            }            
        }
```

keyword is not actually a column in the db it is just a variable I attached to the search model. If the keyword is numeric I consider it an ID, you can ignore this part if you want. Otherwise I concat some fields and search in the result.  You can also not concat the fields and just add a condition for each field, up to you.

You can see the full file at: https://github.com/Mihai-P/yii2-core/blob/master/models/ContactSearch.php

Comment: I want add more options, if try `$query->andFilterWhere([
          'id' => $this->keyword,
          'price' => $this->keyword,
        ]);` but in that case, search is broke and work only with `"/[A-Za-z]+/"` Are you can help me?